# "Ich müsste lügen, wenn ich behauptete, es interessiere mich gerade, was sie tat."

Tags: grammar, subjunctive, indirect-speech

Ist dieser Satz korrekt?

> "Ich müsste lügen, wenn ich behauptete, es interessiere mich gerade, was sie tat."

Dieser Satz stammt aus einem Text, der von einem Ich-Erzähler im Imperfekt erzählt wird. Folgender Sachverhalt soll beschrieben werden:

Person A erzählt zum Zeitpunkt 1 einer Person B, wie Person A zum Zeitpunkt 2 Desinteresse über die Handlungen von Person C zu Zeitpunkt 2 empfunden hat.

"Gerade" bezieht sich auf den Zeitpunkt 2, zu dem die innere Handlung stattfindet, also zu dem des Empfindens von Desinteresse, nicht auf den Zeitpunkt, zu dem dieser Satz gesagt wird.

Meine Überlegungen sind die folgenden:

- "Interessiere" ist Konjunktiv I Präsens wegen der indirekten Rede.
- "Behauptete" ist Konjunktiv II Imperfekt, um Nichtwirklichkeit auszudrücken, denn es wurde nicht tatsächlich behauptet, sondern nur gedacht.

Ist der folgende Satz eine Alternative?

> "Ich müsste lügen, würde ich behaupten, es interessiere mich gerade, was sie tat."

Wie muss der Satz richtig lauten?

Comment: Problematisch ist doch vor allem _interessiere_. Wie der Satz dasteht, findet das eindeutig zum Zeitpunkt 1 statt.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Näheres darüber, wie sie funktioniert, findest du im [help].

Comment: @Jan Nimmt man im Deutschen Touren? Ich dachte, man macht welche...

Comment: @Robert Gute Frage … Hast wahrscheinlich recht. Kommt davon, sich zu viel in zwei Sprachen herumzutreiben xD

Comment: @Jan Erledigt :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich sehe zwei Probleme in Deinem Satz:

- die Verwendung von *müssen*, für die ich in Deinem Szenario keine Rechtfertigung entdecken kann
- *gerade* stellt einen Bezug zu Zeitpunkt 1 her, nicht wie gewünscht Zeitpunkt 2. @chirlu hat korrekt darauf hingewiesen, dass das an *interessiere* liegt, das in der falschen Zeitform daherkommt.

Eine mögliche Lösung wäre

> Ich würde lügen, behauptete ich, es interessierte mich in jenem Moment, was sie tat.

Das klingt aber in meinen Ohren schon eher wie ein Satz aus einem Roman des 19. Jahrhunderts. Etwas einfacher erscheint mir

> Ich kann nicht sagen, dass mich interessierte, was sie tat.

oder schlicht und direkt

> Es interessierte mich nicht, was sie tat.

---

**Ergänzung:** Eine Variante, in der *müssen* tatsächlich eine Berechtigung hat:

> Ich müsste lügen, wollte ich behaupten, dass es mich in jenem Moment interessierte, was sie tat.

Comment: ich finde allerdings, dass version 3 eine nuance weglässt, die der autor wahrscheinlich gewollt hatte. ich finde durch das ``ich müsste lügen`` kommt der erzähler sehr überheblich rüber, so als wäre es unter seiner würde überhaupt interesse zu zeigen...

Comment: @Arnim Keine Frage, die Wirkung dieser Sätze ist sehr unterschiedlich. Allerdings hat der OP eben nur den wiederzugebenden Sachverhalt beschrieben, hingegen nichts zum Sprachniveau oder zur beabsichtigten Wirkung gesagt.

Comment: Danke für die schnelle Antwort! Es gibt doch diese Redewendung "Ich müsste lügen, wenn...". Der Satz soll an die Floskel angelehnt sein, ansonsten hat müssen keine echte Notwendigkeit.

Comment: @Matthias stimmt, allerdings ist mir soeben aufgefallen, dass das ``gerade`` im text nicht unbedingt für den zeitpunkt, sondern für die quantifizierung des interesses steht. ich denke da an sätze wie ``ich bin nicht gerade sehr interessiert``. btw es ist arMiN, nicht arNiM xD

Comment: @Armin So könnte man es tatsächlich auch verstehen, aber in diesem Fall steht "gerade" für den Zeitpunkt :)

Comment: @Armin Sorry für die Verwechslung. Dass _gerade_ temporär gemeint ist, steht in der Frage, aber dass es auch anders verstanden werden könnte, ist ein Grund, warum ich es durch _in jenem Moment_ ersetzt habe.

Comment: @Kizunacat Danke für das schnelle Feedback! Ich glaube, dass Wendungen mit "Ich müsste lügen" gerne mal falsch konstruiert werden. Ich habe ein Beispiel ergänzt, in dem es funktionieren würde. Aber sorry - ich bin zu müde, um noch gut erklären zu können, warum ich es in dem Fall für richtig halte und in Deinem Satz nicht.

Comment: @Matthias Vielen Dank für die Ergänzung! Das ist genau das, wonach ich gesucht habe. :) Verstehe ich schon, ist ja auch schon recht spät! :)